# Reading from a socket until certain character is in buffer

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, berkeley-sockets

I am trying to read from a socket into a buffer until a certain character is reached using `read(fd, buf, BUFFLEN)`.

For example, the socket will receive two lots of information separated by a blank line in one read call.

Is it possible to put the read call in a loop so it stops when it reaches this blank line, then it can read the rest of the information later if it is required?

Comment: If I have correct interpretation of your problem,you wanna display the first lot of info then idle a couple of seconds for the next one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple approach would be to read a single byte at a time until the previous byte and the current byte are new-line characters, as two consecutive new-line characters is a blank line:

```
size_t buf_idx = 0;
char buf[BUFFLEN] = { 0 };

while (buf_idx < BUFFLEN && 1 == read(fd, &buf[buf_idx], 1)
{
    if (buf_idx > 0          && 
        '\n' == buf[buf_idx] &&
        '\n' == buf[buf_idx - 1])
    {
        break;
    }
    buf_idx++;
}
```

Any unread data will have to be read at some point if newly sent data is to be read.

Comment: A character at a time was my initial thought as well, but I'm having difficulty getting it to read it one at a time:
inline `
    int rlen;
    int i = 0;
    while ((rlen = read(proxyFd, &buf[i], 1)) > 0)
    {
      
     if (strstr(&buf[0], "\n\n"))
     {
      printf("bingo\n");
      break;
     }
     i += rlen;
    }
`

Comment: @DMcB1888, you only ever comparing the first two characters in `buf` to `"\n\n"` as you use `buf[0]`. Try `strstr(&buf[i - 1], "\n\n")` but **make** sure `i > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to read from the socket if you want to access this information later, otherwise it will be lost. I think best implementation would be to keep looping reading from the socket, while another process/thread is launched to perform any operation you want when a blank like is received.